# Change package name when running setup.py

Tags: python, git, clone, setuptools

I have forked a repo and now I have cloned it. When running the setup.py file inside, Python installs the package inside site-packages as an obscure name, that of which importing this within a Python file will not be viable.

For example, I fork and clone a repo called `foo`. I can also see this in the setup.py file:

```
setup(
    name='foo',
    version='3.3.0-rc6',
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    include_package_data=True,
```

When I run `python setup.py install`, I find the package has been installed as `foo-3.3.0rc6-py3.6.egg`. I do not want to have to import the package as this name in every one of my projects utilizing it.

How can I just change the package name to `foo` (when running/installing via setup.py), so that I can run `import foo` and not `import foo-3.3...`?

I feel I can not just rename it, as if I wanted other users to clone the repo and not have to go through the same trouble as me. Is the package name embedded somewhere in the setup.py folder?

Let me know if you need anything else, I'm willing to have this issue resolved.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What is your directory structure like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to import `foo-3.3`; actually you cannot import as it's `SyntaxError`.

You don't have to import `foo-3.3` from `foo-3.3.0rc6-py3.6.egg` because distutils/setuptools configured correct import path for eggs. Look into `easy-install.pth` file and you find there `./foo-3.3.0rc6-py3.6.egg`. Run `python` and verify `sys.path` — there have to be `foo-3.3.0rc6-py3.6.egg` entry so that `import foo` works.

Comment: Oops, my bad! I didn't think I would've been able to import it, since the real packages were inside the .egg folder. It made confused is all. Thanks for the tips, I'm able to import the packages I cloned.

Answer (score 2):

That's just the name of the egg, and you needn't worry about it. Python knows where to look for the package, so when you do:

```
import foo
```

...it'll do the right thing.